# Angular 2/4 access directive data within component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a **trigger** directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[trigger]'
})

export class trigger {

    constructor(private svc: toggleService) {}

    @HostListener('click') onToggle() {
        this.svc.toggle();
    }
}
```

I also have a **target** directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[target]'
})

export class target {

    constructor(private svc: toggleService) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        this.svc.onToggle.subscribe(
        (toggleState: boolean) => {
            this.toggleState = toggleState
        }
    }

}
```

They communicate between them via a service. The communication works fine - the target is successfully receiving a boolean state from the trigger.

```
<component-one>
   <button trigger></button>
</component-one>

<component-two>
   <div target></div>
</component-two>
```

If I console log within the target, I get the correct toggleState. But how do I make the toggleState available within component-two?

Comment: Since you have a service, why not storing it in it ?

Comment: You could subscribe to the state inside component-two also, since you do have the service

Comment: I'm building a UI framework and, so I wish to make the directive agnostic. The point is that the directives, used in tandem, will do all the lifting. This way I can avoid having to import the service in the components it is used in.

Comment: you need to make component-two listen to a subscription of his child... but you don t know who is his child... so the only solution that I found all his child should implement the same interface that containt a method that return a subject.. so the parent can subscribe this this subject and receive the data ... how you going to handle all the children? the anwser is using @ViewChildren

Comment: So without subscribing in component-two, I have no way of making the target-directive's data available?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use @output in directive like this

```
@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter()
```

and in the function use

```
(toggleState: boolean) => {
            this.toggleState = toggleState
            this.valueChange.emit(toggleState)
        }
```

in the button you will have to use

```
<div trigger (valueChange)="triggerChange($event)"></div>
```

than you can will get the value in triggerChange function which you can send to the second component using @input property

Or simply you can use service as described in the comments

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. I already have an EventEmitter in the service, which is how I communicate between the directives - the target directive subscribes to changes in the service. I wanted to know though if I can make the value from the target directive available in component-two, without subscribing within component-two.